# JQuery How to add a Accordion inside a Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog hidden by default that when the user clicks in a button in the page, the dialog appears and inside the dialog there is a accordion. The accordion appears BUT each section of the accordion does not appear complete. It does not show the text inside each accordion section completely. It just shows the first line.

```
$('#helpx').hide();
$('#accord').accordion({ header: 'h3' });

$('#helpbutton').click(function() { 
    if ( $('#helpx').is(':visible') == false ) { 
        $('#helpx').show().dialog({height: 600, width:550, dialogClass: 'shadowme', position: [390,130]}); 
            }
    else { $('#helpx').dialog('close'); }
});
```

Remember that the accordion is inside the tags of the dialog in the html. For instance

```
<div id="helpx" title="Sistema de Ayuda">
    <div id="accord">
```

Comment: there's got to be something wrong in your html.  let's see some more code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems seems to work fine for me but we really need to see your code

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
$('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen:false});
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
})
```

here is [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/7kZpR/)